# Vs2017: An Error Occured while finding the resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, data-binding, resourcedictionary

Am getting the below error when i tried to refer the resource dictionary my app.xaml file

```
<Application x:Class="DesignerPoc.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesignerPoc"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Dashboard.Designer.WPF;Connection/Views/test.xaml"/>
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </Application.Resources>
```

Error

`An Error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "pack://application:,,,/Dashboard.Designer.WPF;Connection/Views/test.xaml"`

[refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIbjR.png)

How to resolve this.??

Comment: Have you build your project after you added that resource? Sometimes VS designer requires a build to find resources. Also, when you run the application does it throw an exception that the resource cannot be found?

Comment: yes. when i build shows build successful without any errors but when i run my project application entered into a break state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris) is wrong.

It should look like this, including the `component` part:

```
pack://application:,,,/Dashboard.Designer.WPF;component/Connection/Views/test.xaml
```