# Vs2017: An Error Occured while finding the resource dictionary with component tagged

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having the same problem as this post, but already did the suggested correction and no luck:

[Vs2017: An Error Occured while finding the resource dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048632/vs2017-an-error-occured-while-finding-the-resource-dictionary/51515366#51515366)

My resource is like this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/FIT.Windows.Forms;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

But i can't preview the form:

[image]

Exception Text:

> An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "pack://application:,,,/FIT.Windows.Forms;component/Themes/Generic.xaml".

Stack Trace :

> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.InstanceBuilders.ResourceDictionaryInstanceBuilder.ProvideResourceDictionary(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, IDocumentRoot& relatedRoot, ResourceDictionary& originalInstance)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.InstanceBuilders.ResourceDictionaryInstanceBuilder.UpdateProperty(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, IProperty propertyKey, DocumentNode valueNode)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.InstanceBuilders.ResourceDictionaryInstanceBuilder.InstantiateProperties(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, DocumentCompositeNode compositeNode)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.DictionaryInstanceBuilder.Initialize(ILocalInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, Boolean isNewInstance)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.InstanceBuilders.LocalInstanceManager.InitializeInstance(IInstanceBuilder builder, ViewNode viewNode, Boolean isNewInstance)

Comment: Hi, please post the exception as text as [edit] of your question.

Comment: Hi, this only happens in the new VS 2017.

Comment: Have you migrated the solution recently? If so, try to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders, it might resolve the issue after a full rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

My solution came with a new solution file from sctrach.
That seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a workaround:

1. Exclude the affected file from your project and include it back in
2. Save and build solution

This works if the resource file worked before and is "randomly" not accessible anymore.